# A closed-form for $\int_1^\infty x^{-\frac{a}{2}}e^{-x}\cos(a b\log x)dx, $ when $a,b>1$

Tags: integration, closed-form

Yesterday I've found this problem from some calculations that I did

> **Question.** For $a>1$ and $b>1$, calculate in a closed-form (if it is possible find such closed-form) in terms of $a$ and $b$ the integral $$\int_1^\infty x^{-\frac{a}{2}}e^{-x}\cos(a\cdot b\log x)dx.
> $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If isn't possible I am interesting in recurrences when we define such integral as $$I(a,b)=\int_1^\infty x^{-\frac{a}{2}}e^{-x}\cos(a\cdot b\log x)dx$$ being $a=n\geq 1$ an integer. Thus with this comment I am saying that previous **Question**  isn't modified as you see, and I would like to know your comments about if it's possible get a recurrence for $I(n,b)$, where $n\geq 1$ and integer and $b>1$ a real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-a/2}\expo{-x}\cos\pars{ab\ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\Re\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-a/2}\expo{-x}\expo{\ic ab\ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\Re\int_{1}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} \over x^{a\pars{1/2 - b\ic}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\Re\pars{\mrm{E}_{a\pars{1/2 - b\ic}}\pars{1}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\mrm{E}_{p}\pars{z}}$ is the [Generalized Exponential Integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19.E2).

Comment: Many thanks, this afternoon I will study your answer and reference to the Generalized Exponential Integral.

Comment: @user243301 You're welcome.